# Could not resolve property Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, restriction

I have 2 entities whose extracts are like these:

```
public class Visita {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="pdv_uid")
    private PuntoDeVenta pdv;
}

public class PuntoDeVenta {
    private Integer idclient;

    private String zona;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pdv_categoria_uid", nullable=true)
    private PuntoDeVentaCategoria categoria;
}

public class PuntoDeVentaCategoria {
    private String descripcion;
}
```

I try to do restrictions with the differents fields and some of them work, some of them don't.

With this root criteria:

```
Criteria criteria =   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Visita.class).createAlias("pdv", "pdv");
```

I try to make restrictions with the differents fields of "PuntoDeVenta" and "PuntoDeVentaCategoria" (with and without the createAlias) and I get the exception "could not resolve property", for example:

```
Criteria criteria =   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Visita.class).createAlias("pdv", "pdv").add(Restrictions.eq("pdv.categoria.descripcion", "example"));
```

I've researching and I didn't found anything for my case.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you add get / set method to show in the query the path

Comment: I have getter and setter in the class, but I just put a extract of the class(it's huge)

Comment: Apply a double alias. The first is pdv, the second on categoria

Comment: I saw it in other solutions...but I don't know if it's correct in my case

Comment: all of them outside "Visita"

Comment: try that: `.createCriteria(Visita.class).createAlias("pdv", "pdv").createAlias("pdv.categoria", "categoria").add(Restrictions.eq("categoria.descripcion", "example"));`