# Could not resolve property in Hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have 2 entities whose extracts are like these:

```
public class Visita {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="pdv_uid")
    private PuntoDeVenta pdv;
}

public class PuntoDeVenta {
    private Integer idclient;

    private String zona;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pdv_categoria_uid", nullable=true)
    private PuntoDeVentaCategoria categoria;
}

public class PuntoDeVentaCategoria {
    private String descripcion;
}
```

I try to do restrictions with the differents fields and some of them work, some of them don't.

With this root criteria:

```
Criteria criteria =   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Visita.class).createAlias("pdv", "pdv");
```

I try to make restrictions with the differents fields of "PuntoDeVenta" and "PuntoDeVentaCategoria" (with and without the createAlias) and I get the exception "could not resolve property", for example:

```
Criteria criteria =   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Visita.class).createAlias("pdv", "pdv").add(Restrictions.eq("pdv.categoria.descripcion", "example"));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not resolve property Hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176915/could-not-resolve-property-hibernate)

Comment: In your code there are many annotations missing, but we consider that they exist.

Answer (score 2):

Add one more line.

```
Criteria criteria =   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Visita.class).createAlias("pdv", "pdv");

criteria.createAlias("pdv.categoria", "categoria");
```

Now it work in way below

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("categoria.descripcion", "example"));
```

Comment: I didnt try your code yet, but, for example, this query doesnt work either: Criteria criteria =   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Visita.class).createAlias("pdv", "pdv").add(Restrictions.eq("pdv.zona", "example")); and I created the alias for pdv...

Comment: "pdv.zona" should work, and zona field is annoted with @Column right?

Comment: it isn't annoted with @column because it has the same name than in the DB. Should I annoted it? I thought when it's the same name than in the DB it doesn't need that annotation

Comment: if you want name than write @Column(name="colName") and dont want than write @Column. ultimately hibernate should aware about this column so [at]Column is required.